# get value of timepicker on changed , not submit

Tags: android

I am really struggling with somthing that is probably really simple.

I have a time picker with an id of timePicker1 and when it is changed I want to instantly change the time in a text box with an id of echoTime. Now when the activity starts it displays the current time from the time picker. But when I scroll through the hours and minutes I need it to change the value in my textView echoTime.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

Here is file :

```
 public class AddNormal extends Activity {







 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.add_normal);


// the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog




//TimePicker timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
//timePicker1.clearFocus();
//int hour = timePicker1.getCurrentHour();
//int minute = timePicker1.getCurrentMinute();

    //TextView echoTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.echoTime);



        //echoTime.setText(hour +":"+ minute );



 }





void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
TextView echoTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.echoTime);



echoTime.setText(hourOfDay +":"+ minute );


}

      };
```

Thanks In advabce peeps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Call `setOnTimeChangedListener()` on the `TimePicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setOnTimeChangedListener%28android.widget.TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener%29) and provide an implementation of `OnTimeChangedListener` to be notified when the time in the `TimePicker` changes.

Comment: Thankyou, I have added that to my code but it dosnt add the text when the time has changed.

Comment: @BarryConnolly: If you think that your edited code in your question followed my instructions, you are sorely mistaken.